# Checking username availability with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

This is my first ever try on Ajax, what this code is doing is that when a user types a username, ajax should get triggered and tell the user whether the username is available of not. But ajax file is not doing what it is suppose to do in other words the function is not getting triggered. any idea why?

I have taken this example from a book.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="bootstrap/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Ajax -->
    <script src="ajax.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

    <!-- Ajax -->
    <script src="checkusername.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="checkusername.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Registration Form</legend>
                <p>
                Username: <br> <input name="username" onchange="check_username(this.form.username.value)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" maxlength="20"  style="width:200px; display: inline;">
                <span id="username_label"></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                Password: <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" style="width:200px;">
                </p>

                <p>
                Confirm Password: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" maxlength="20" style="width:200px;">
                </p>

                <p>
                First Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20" style="width:200px;">
                </p>
                <p>
                Last Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="20" style="width:200px;">
                </p>
                <p>
                Email: <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" maxlength="20" style="width:200px;">
                </p>

                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" >Register</button>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### ajax.js

```
var ajax = false;

if( window.XMLHttpRequest ){

    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

if ( !ajax ) {
    alert('functionality is not avaible');
}
```

### checkusername.js

```
function check_username( username ){

    if( ajax ){
        ajax.onreadystatechange = handle_check;
        ajax.open( 'GET', 'checkusername.php?username=' + encodeURIComponent(username), true);
        ajax.send(null);
    }
    else{

        document.getElementById( 'username_label' ).innerHTML = 'The availablity of this username will be check upon form submission';
    }
}

function handle_check(){

    if ( ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200 ) {
        document.getElementById( 'username_label' ).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
}
```

### checkusername.PHP

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['username'])) {

        $dbc = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','testdb') OR die ( 'Cannot connect.' );

        $que = sprintf("SELECT ID FROM maintable WHERE name='%s'", mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $_GET['username'] ) ));

        $runque = mysqli_query( $dbc, $que );

        if (mysqli_num_rows( $runque ) == 1) {
            echo "The Username is unavaiable!";
        }
        else{
            echo "The Username is avaiable!";
        }

        mysqli_close( $dbc );

    }
    else{
        echo "Please Enter username";
    }

?>
```

Comment: checkout your console log and see

Comment: check your browser network call. press f12 and click on network tab

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the `%s` in your `SELECT` statement. `mysqli_real_escape_string` will add them as needed. For example: The string `foo'bar` will be escaped to `'foo\'bar'`

Comment: @Dinesh ah! mate idk how and why but my browser loaded my js after going into network tab. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Kyoya Mate it was not about the query, my php worked fine.And this  '%s' should be in single quotes. 
Thanks for ya time tho. My programs is working now.